# An index of the The Economist's Schools Brief series

Tags: reference-request

I was wondering whether anyone might have an index of the articles that made up the *The Economist*'s Schools Brief series that ran from 1975 to 1999 (with a brief refresh in 2013)?

They were an interesting set of articles that explained economic concepts (with a free market slant, of course, being *The Economist*) in an easy and accessible form.

Answer (score 6):

The Economist has some articles online from 1999 onwards: this is a partial selection of some which seemed interesting, though not quite what you are looking for

1999

- https://www.economist.com/unknown/1999/10/21/finance-trick-or-treat
- https://www.economist.com/unknown/1999/11/04/moneyed-men-in-institutions
- https://www.economist.com/unknown/1999/11/11/stocks-in-trade
- https://www.economist.com/unknown/1999/11/18/monopoly-power-over-money
- https://www.economist.com/unknown/1999/12/09/the-future-of-finance

2013

- https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/2013/09/05/explaining-the-schools-briefs
- https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/2013/09/07/crash-course
- https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/2013/09/14/lending-weight
- https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/2013/09/21/controlling-interest
- https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/2013/09/28/sovereign-doubts
- https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/2013/10/03/calling-to-accounts

2016

- https://www.economist.com/leaders/2016/07/21/breakthroughs-and-brickbats
- https://www.economist.com/news/2016/08/04/which-economists-have-had-the-greatest-impact
- https://www.economist.com/economics-brief/2016/07/23/secrets-and-agents
- https://www.economist.com/economics-brief/2016/07/30/minskys-moment
- https://www.economist.com/economics-brief/2017/08/03/gary-beckers-concept-of-human-capital
- https://www.economist.com/economics-brief/2016/08/06/an-inconvenient-iota-of-truth
- https://www.economist.com/economics-brief/2016/08/11/where-does-the-buck-stop
- https://www.economist.com/economics-brief/2016/08/20/prison-breakthrough
- https://www.economist.com/economics-brief/2016/08/27/two-out-of-three-aint-bad
- https://www.economist.com/sites/default/files/econbriefs.pdf

2018

- https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2018/04/12/economists-understand-little-about-the-causes-of-growth
- https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2018/04/19/economists-still-lack-a-proper-understanding-of-business-cycles
- https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2018/04/26/many-results-in-microeconomics-are-shaky
- https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2018/05/03/economists-focus-too-little-on-what-people-really-care-about
- https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2018/05/10/barriers-to-entry

This clearly misses the older articles.  Google turned up

- http://marshallinside.usc.edu/joines/549/articles_pdf/ec901103.txt.pdf (Paradigm Lost, November 3, 1990
- [http://people.tamu.edu/~aglass/econ452/Economist2a.pdf](http://people.tamu.edu/%7Eaglass/econ452/Economist2a.pdf) (The Miracle of Trade, 27 January 1996)
- http://walkerd.people.cofc.edu/Readings/Markets/schoolsbrief.pdf (Feb 17 1996 - State and Market)

---

*Added:* The Economist relaunched the series in 2020, which (including some of those listed above) can be found at

- https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/

Answer (score 0):

The economist itself provides an overview, although annoyingly it doesn't include the 1999 articles mentioned by Henry.

https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/?page=1